# Paypal IPN Verified but not running my insert or my log

Tags: windows, iis, server, paypal-ipn

I have some problems with Paypal's ipn.
I have a windows server with IIS, with 2 domains, 1 is in the root folder and the other one is deepest.

www.website.com --> root/index.aspx

www.secondweb.com --> root/website/completed/4/index.aspx

Paypal ipn is verified in both websites because in 
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ works and in https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history&nav=0.3.2 works again.

In my code at the moment there isnt the check of package because I get off almost all my code but I can assecurate thats is verified but I still dont understand why in the website of the root works (write in db and log) and in the other doesnt. This is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" aspcompat=true%>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

<%
Dim IdWeb = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
Dim IdUse
Dim Pac
Dim AllPar
Dim IdDis
Dim MonGra
Dim Price

'Listener Payment 
Dim objHttp, str
' read post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
str = Request.Form.ToString() & "&cmd=_notify-validate"
' post back to PayPal system to validate
objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
' set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
' set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.open("POST", "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false)
objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
objHttp.Send(str)

'Creo e apro connessione
Dim Connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=***;Database=mb")
Dim Command As New MySqlCommand
Command.Connection = Connection
Connection.Open()

' Esecuzione frase SQL
Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO WEBSITE (IDWEB) VALUES ('bbb')"
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

'Chiusura connessione
Connection.Close()

using fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("log.txt"),FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write) 
    using swr = new StreamWriter(fs)
        swr.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")+" ")
        swr.Write("hello")
        swr.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    end using
end using   
%>
```

So I tried to foucs on the configuration about certificate SSL, I think you are right, the problem has to be there cause the rest works and it's the same for both website.
This is my configuration

```
https All unassigned 443
www.website.com
Require server name indication
ssl certificate
website.com

https All unassigned 443
www.secondweb.com
Require server name indication
ssl certificate
secondweb.com
```

I have this warning

> No default SSL site has been created. To support browsers without SNI
>   capabilities, it is recommended to create a default SSL site.

Still the same about my issues, Could be for this warning that still doesnt work?
I have read this

> One thing to note with implementing SNI for your SSL solution, it will
>   not work for those users running Internet Explorer on Windows XP

They do both the same request

```
            <form id="payment" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="***">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MB Website's Production">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M">
                <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
                <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
                <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Mirco---completed------1---0.01">
                <input type="submit" value="Envía">
            </form>
```

The only difference between each other is the position of the websites.

Maybe paypal ipn has some problems with sni?

Answer (score 0):

> Paypal ipn is verified in both websites because in
>   https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ works and in
>   https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history&nav=0.3.2
>   works again.

All this means is that the IPN message was sent, and the endpoint responded with an HTTP 200 OK.

What happens next is what's failing. Your code tries to connect to the `https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate` , which is the first thing that may be failing.  You need to log all possible errors within your code and debug this.  That HTTPS connection may be failing. This may be due to the TLS 1.2 requirement, or it may be due to you not trusting the certificate authority that trusts the issuer of the SSL certificate of that PayPal server endpoint.

And assuming all that is working correctly and you receive a 'VALID' response from the ipn postback endpoint, other problems may be happening later on in your code.

You need to do your own runtime debugging from your environment; we can't debug this code running on your system for you.

Comment: Hi @Preston thank you for the answer, but if for example was for some tls requirement or some issues of my code it shouldn’t run in my other website as well.

Comment: The other websites have the same exact code, webserver environment, and certificate authority lists? Hardly possible. It is definitely a problem that needs to be debugged at runtime. The error will be at execution time.

Comment: How can I debug in runtime, I mean, this is working in "background", it s making me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works!!!
I had to put my ipn page in the root
root/paypal_ipn.aspx
Before I had one ipn page there for the main website and another one for the second website, now I manage everything from just one in the root and everything works!
Thank you